# Constantly Check Through a List of Times and Current Time and Display Notification

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, toast

I'm currently working on a python to-do application. All user created events are stored in a dictionary called toDoEvents, with title, due_time, remind_time, and description. Right now I'm working on a notification system using toast. I need to constantly check the list of remind_dates for every event and if it matches the current time, calls the toast notification.

I want to do something like this, except constantly checking it every time the minute changes:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import time
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDateTime

toDoEvents = {}
class TodoEvent:

    def __init__(self, title, due_time, remind_time, description):
        self.title = title
        self.due_time = due_time
        self.remind_time = remind_time
        self.description = description
        toDoEvents[self.title] = self

    def change_title(self, new_title):
        self.title = new_title

    def change_due_time(self, new_due_time):
        self.due_time = new_due_time

    def change_remind_time(self, new_remind_time):
        self.remind_time = new_remind_time

    def change_description(self, new_description):
        self.description = new_description


event1 = TodoEvent("test", QDateTime(2019, 10, 26, 1, 18).toPyDateTime(), QDateTime(2019, 10, 26, 1, 18).toPyDateTime(), "test description")

for event in toDoEvents.values():

    if event.remind_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M") == datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %I:%M"):
        toaster = ToastNotifier()
        toaster.show_toast(event.title, event.description, threaded=True, icon_path=None, duration=8)
        while toaster.notification_active():
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?
Edit: want to execute code every time the minute changes, not every 60 seconds (which assumes the user starts the program at exactly 0 seconds)

Comment: So you want to run the toaster exactly at hh:mm:00 each minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another answer as the update to the question has made the other one a bit off topic, but I prefer to leave it there as I believe that it could be useful to others, even if slightly unrelated to the topic at matter.

The example below subclasses QTimer making it a timer that "timeouts" at minute changes only. It might seem a bit complicated, but that's due to the nature of QTimers, which *can* be not as precise as one would expect (as most timers are); nonetheless it allows better implementation while avoiding unnecessary timeout signal emissions, as sometimes the timeout signal could be emitted *before* the end of the minute, thus emitting it again when the minute actually changes.

The `singleShot` setting is really not required, as the timer will be restarted anyway with the correct interval (constant checks are required, as some hard working process might happen in the meantime, causing the timer to shift after the minute change). I just added it as I *think* it might slightly improve performance in case of high amount of timers, but I may be wrong. In any case, it will work anyway even without it.

```
class MinuteTimer(QTimer):
    customTimeout = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MinuteTimer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSingleShot(True)
        # default timer is CoarseTimer, which *could* fire up before, making it
        # possible that the timeout is called twice
        self.setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)
        # to avoid unintentional disconnection (as disconnect() without
        # arguments disconnects the signal from *all* slots it's connected
        # to), we "overwrite" the internal timeout signal attribute name by
        # by switching it with our customTimeout signal instead, keeping
        # its consistency with QTimer objects, at least by object naming
        self._internalTimeout = self.timeout
        self._internalTimeout.connect(self.startAdjusted)
        self._internalTimeout.connect(self.customTimeout)
        self.timeout = self.customTimeout

    def start(self):
        now = QTime.currentTime()
        nextMinute = QTime(now.hour(), now.minute()).addSecs(60)
        # if the next minute happens at or after the midnight of the day
        # after (in this specific case, when "now" is at 23:59), msecsTo()
        # will return a negative value, since QTime has no date reference:
        # 14:30:00 to 14:29:00 is -60 seconds, so 23:59:00 to 00:00:00 is
        # -86340 seconds; using the % modulus operator against the
        # millisecond count in a day can give us the correct positive
        # difference that can be used as an interval for QTimer
        QTimer.start(self, now.msecsTo(nextMinute) % 86400000)

    def startAdjusted(self):
        now = QTime.currentTime()
        # even when using a PreciseTimer, it is possible that the timeout
        # is called before the minute change; if that's the case, we
        # add 2 minutes, just to be "better safe than sorry"
        addSecs = 120 if now.second() > 50 else 60
        nextMinute = QTime(now.hour(), now.minute()).addSecs(addSecs)
        QTimer.start(self, now.msecsTo(nextMinute) % 86400000)


def minuteEvent():
    print('minute changed!')

    for event in toDoEvents.values():
        if event.remind_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M") == datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %I:%M"):
            toaster = ToastNotifier()
            toaster.show_toast(event.title, event.description, 
                threaded=True, icon_path=None, duration=8)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    minuteTimer = MinuteTimer()
    minuteTimer.timeout.connect(minuteEvent)
    minuteTimer.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Obviously, it is possible that the timer emits its signal before the minute change (resulting in a failed notification if the next signal is emitted after its minute change), but that's mostly due to your implementation, and I believe that's up to you to check for a time range to ensure that each todo is catched when it should be.
As a possible alternative, you can emit a signal with the expected "HH:mm" timing (using statements similar to the `addSecs = 120 if now.second() > 50 else 60` I used) and then check for the actual timing of the reminder.

Comment: I hate to tell you, but when I run the program, it doesn't work. I think its because Startadjusted is never called.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the minuteTimer.start(), but that's a bit obvious, if I may...

Comment: You're welcome! I've updated the answer with some more information. Btw, I realized that my last comment might have seemed a bit rude, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, I'm writing almost the same type of program, and I'd suggest to use [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) instead of constantly checking the current time. Anyway since QTimer default timing has a 5% interval margin (which might be very high for long intervals), you might want to set its [timerType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timerType-prop) to `Qt.PreciseTimer`.

```
class TodoEvent:

    def __init__(self, title, due_time, remind_time, description):
        self.title = title
        self.due_time = due_time
        self.remind_time = remind_time
        self.description = description
        toDoEvents[self.title] = self
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showReminder)
        self.timer.setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.change_remind_time(remind_time)

    def change_title(self, new_title):
        self.title = new_title

    def change_due_time(self, new_due_time):
        self.due_time = new_due_time

    def change_remind_time(self, new_remind_time):
        self.remind_time = new_remind_time
        self.timer.start(QDateTime.currentDateTime().msecsTo(self.remind_time))

    def change_description(self, new_description):
        self.description = new_description

    def showReminder(self):
        toaster = ToastNotifier()
        toaster.show_toast(self.title, self.description, threaded=True, icon_path=None, duration=8)

event1 = TodoEvent("test", 
                   QDateTime(2019, 10, 26, 1, 18), 
                   QDateTime(2019, 10, 26, 1, 18), 
                   "test description")
```

Note that QTimer intervals are expressed in milliseconds as *integer*, so there might problems with date intervals higher than the maximum value of a 32bit integer. Standard integers have a maximum positive value of 2147483647, which, when referred to milliseconds, is 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes, 23 seconds and 647 ms.

This means that if you have a reminder due to a date with a ms interval higher than that value, you'll get an invalid timer (with an interval equal to -1).
While it's unlikely that a normal person will keep his/her computer on for that amount of time, that's not impossible (think about portable devices that often run for weeks without restarting), so you might want to add a function that checks the due time for too high intervals and, eventually, add a further timer that will "restore" itself until the interval has become valid, then start the actual timer for the notification.

Comment: What do you mean by problems with date intervals? I just want it to execute the if every time the time changes by a minute.

Comment: Your question wasn't very clear about it, so I added a possible answer based on what I understood. I'll might add another answer instead of editing/deleting this one, as I still believe that it might be helpful anyway. Just to be clear, the fact that you're using QDateTime is related to the program implementation? Because if it's not, you should probably remove it at all.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation caused any confusion. And to answer your question above, yes, I want it to execute at hh:mm:00 each minute. Edit: When the user enters the remind time it is based on a QDateTimeEdit, so it has to be a datetime (unless there is a way to convert it to something more easier to manage).

Comment: No problem :-) What about the QDateTime question? Is Qt a requirement and are you using its event loop?

Comment: No, Qt isn't a requirement (I have QDateTime converted to datetime). I thought of having a QTimer at first, but I don't know how to make the code execute every time the minute changes. If there's another way/easier way to do this, I'd like to hear it!

Comment: I might be mistake, but I also noticed that the timer only starts when change_remind_time is called. Edit: nevermind, didn't see the last line in the init.

Comment: Sorry for so many comments, but my program doesn't run with the above code. My program uses pickle to write the toDoEvents dictionary to a file. I guess it has something to do with storing active qtimers?

Comment: @SilentBeast it's possible, as it depends on how you [re]store timings. In my program I used QDateTime.toString(Qt.ISODate) to store datetimes and QDateTime.fromString(Qt.ISODate) to retrieve them. While I'm using json instead of pickle, that would work anyway, no matter the serialization method you are using.